# transferring values from request to response (soapUI mock service)

Tags: soap, mocking, request, response, soapui

I'm receiving a 15 digit user ID and wanna trim its last 3 digit then send back to request sender. Request sample is below :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <lookupSubscriberInfo xmlns="http://testID.com/V1_0">
         <callingParty>testParty</callingParty>
         <subscriberRequestList>
            <testId>888905425616681</opaqueId>
         </subscriberRequestList>
      </lookupSubscriberInfo>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have read this
http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html
but could not figure out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not do it by XPATH on the other hand XmlSlurper has worked..

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
def parsedContent = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
context.MSISDN = parsedContent.Body.lookupSubscriberInfo.subscriberRequestList.opaqueId.toString().substring(3,15)
```

In order to use MSISDN value ou should use the following

${MSISDN}