# SoapUI getting XML request parameters in mock service script

Tags: soapui

I am trying to read the PresentationID xml value received by a SoapUI mockService, I send in a POST request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentRequest xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
    <PresentationID>test41</PresentationID>
</ContentRequest>
```

I can see that the request payload I send is correct + "Content-Type" header is application/xml

But in SoapUI those will always print: null

```
 log.info mockRequest.getContentElement()
 log.info mockRequest.requestContent
 log.info mockRequest.getRequestXmlObject()
```

I read both: [SoapUI getting request parameters in mock service script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945403/soapui-getting-request-parameters-in-mock-service-script)

[transferring values from request to response (soapUI mock service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738362/transferring-values-from-request-to-response-soapui-mock-service)

And also tried the SoapUI tutorial: http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html
but no success yet..

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!
I am using SoapUI 5.0.0

Comment: No issue here with SoapUI 5.1.2. All three lines output something.

Answer (score -2):

I just had the same issue.
Updating Soap-UI to the latest release http://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html solved the problem.

log.info mockRequest.getContentElement() 
still returns null, but the other two are working fine.

Happy Testing :)